# ProgresBar - display message after the bar reaches 100%

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, tms

I am playing around with progress bars ... trying to display a message when the progress bar reaches the end of the line (100%) ( I used the Raize Status bar and TMS AdvProgressBar) 
For Raize, this code sample seem to work :

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  rzprogressstatus1.Percent := rzprogressstatus1.Percent +1;
  if rzprogressstatus1.Percent = 100 then begin
    showmessage('Yo');
    application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

However,for AdvProgressBar it does not because it keeps firing messages constantly when 
position reaches 100.That makes me worry if Raize is maybe in trouble.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdvProgressBar1.Position := AdvProgressBar1.Position +1;
  if AdvProgressBar1.Position = 100 then begin
    showmessage('Yo');
    application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

edit :
debugger shows :

> First chance exception at $00649D6C. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00649d6c: read of address 0x00000048'. Process Project1.exe (2928)  and stops on the following code :

```
procedure TTimer.SetEnabled(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FEnabled then begin
    FEnabled := Value;
    UpdateTimer;
  end;
end;
```

Like I said,I would like to display a message when the bar reaches the end and then terminate the application. What am I missing here ? Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: So, what happens. The message does not show? Position is never equal to 100? Make it clear what happens? Tell us what your debugging yielded.

Comment: Am I doing the right thing in the first place ? The position in both cases reaches 100%,all right....

Comment: The code doesn't look good. But it's not the real code anyway. Showing dialogs from timers look dubious. Does the dialog show?

Comment: Yes, the message shows.... I am skeptic also for messages with timers and that's why I also asked if there's another way around this...just learning ...

Comment: It's not clear why you are seeing an access violation. However, it's wrong to show the dialog whilst the timer is still active. The timer event will fire again and again inside the model message loop of the dialog. So the timer event handler is re-entrant. But I've no idea what you are really trying to do. Surely you are not trying to measure the progress of timer events.

Comment: Definitely stop the timer when your progress bar reaches its max value. And do it as the first thing before you show the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use a timer and you do something time consuming (showing a dialog is time consuming) you should always turn the timer off at the start of the timer event and turn it on again at the end (if neccessary)

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  AdvProgressBar1.Position := AdvProgressBar1.Position +1;
  if AdvProgressBar1.Position = 100 then begin
    showmessage('Yo');
    application.Terminate;
  end;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: Stopping and starting timer is unecessary. Just put the line `Timer1.Enabled := False;` just before the message is shown and the timer will stop once and forever.

Comment: Its just a general advise when working with timers. It just saves you a lot of headaches when timers fire unexpectedly.

Comment: Really ? I've never seen and would never suggest something like this. At least because you should never put long running tasks in timers. And it is unessesarily expensive to create that hidden window for its message loop just because you can't process a code that should be processed between timer ticks.

Comment: Might be that using timers that way is is quick and dirty but for small tools I would not care. I guess it depends  on your needs. Nevertheless I think the comments here are the wrong place to discuss the correct use of timers ;-)

Comment: Ok, let's clean it up. You can stay at you fear from message box shown only in one case ;-)

Comment: How is the timer event going to be re-entrant? Might be worth explaining that. This one will be. But if it isn't, and they should not be ideally, then your advice is not needed.